# N command pipe " Inter-process "

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, pipe

I have successfully piped the output of one command by using one pipe .

I want to do this with N successive commands where each command represent a process .

This is my attempt at pipelining one command ,So to make a N sequence of command do i need n-1 pipes ? and how the father of all processes can collect the output and print it .

and thank you .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc ,char *argv[])
{
    int i,pid;
    int fd[2];//crea i descriptor 
    char phrase[30][30];//crea il buffer
    pipe(fd); /* crea la pipe */

    for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
    {
        if((pid=fork())==0)
        {               
            strcpy(phrase[i], argv[i+1]);  
            printf("ho scritoo :'%s'\n",phrase);
            close(fd[0]);                         /* chiude in lettura */
            write(fd[1],phrase[i],strlen(phrase[i])+1); /* invia anche 0x00 */
            close (fd[1]);                   // chiude in scrittura
            // pid=0 -> figlio
            usleep(50000*(1+i));      // Ritardo iniziale
            printf("Figlio: %d\n",i+1);   // Stampa messaggio del figlio
            usleep(500000*(1+i));     // Ritardo finale
            return(101+i);            // Termina con codice di ritorno
        } else { 
            printf("Ho generato il figlio %d con pid %d\n",i+1,pid);
            char message[100];    //creare il buffer 
            memset(message,0,100);
            int bytesread;  

            bytesread = read(fd[0],message,sizeof(message));
            printf("ho letto dalla pipe %d bytes: '%s' \n",bytesread,message);
            // close(fd[0]);
        }
    }
    close(fd[0]);                         /* chiude in scrittura */
    close(fd[1]);                         /* chiude in scrittura */
    // Attende che dieci processi terminino
    for(i=0;i<argc-1;i++)
    {
        int status;
        wait(&status);      // Attende termine di un figlio (uno qualunque)
        printf("Terminato processo %d\n",WEXITSTATUS(status));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have N-1 pipes for N processes. You could just have all the processes print to stdout. Since each child process will inherit the parent's stdout, they will all print to whatever the parent's stdout is set to. If you start the chain by redirecting stdout to a file, then they will all print to that file. The problem will synchronizing their writes so that they don't write in the middle of another's write.

If you want to pipe all child output back up to the original parent, you could have each child just write to its parent's pipe everything it reads from its own child's pipe. Each child passing it up the chain in this manner.

Comment: I edit my code and i succeed to implement N number of child processes ,where the parent can read one at time from a child .      the problem is that i want that the parent process read all the processes input in one time .

Comment: My input was : ./pipes cmd1 cmd2 cmd3                               I created the first child with pid 21552
 I wrote: 'cmd1'
 I read from the pipe 4 bytes: 'cmd1'
 I created the second child with pid 21553
 I wrote: 'cmd2' 
I read from the pipe 4 bytes:'cmd2'
 I created the third child with pid 21554
 I write: 'cmd3'
 I read from the pipe 4 bytes:'cmd3'
 Son: 1
 Son: 2
 Son: 3
 Ended process 101
 Ended process 102
 Ended process 103